# vi replacing characters on file opening

Tags: vim

Whenever I open an existing file with `vim`, the first non-blank character in one of the lines gets replaced with a g.

I might have entered a command by mistake (since I usually forget to switch to insert mode before pasting text from another terminal/window).

I have tried to delete the .vimrc file, but it has not solved the problem.

Has anyone ever had such a problem? And solved it?

I am on Amazon Linux, version 2015.09

Comment: Does that also happen when you open vim with `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: @pfnuesel No, it doesn't.

Comment: What does `vim -c scriptnames` give?

Comment: @marinus it starts as with the `vim` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two known causes for this. The first is a bug in VIM that causes it to misinterpret the transparency value in the URxvt.background setting in the .Xresources o

The second is a problem with some older versions of MobaXterm. That affected me and updating to the latest version (8.6) resolved the issue for me.

Comment: It's coming from MobaXterm. I'll see if I can update.